# How to check if a word begins with 'x' in an array in php

Tags: php, laravel

**Foreground**: I have this project I'm working on which uses email templates stored in database, each email body contain several shortcodes in the pattern  `{{$shortcode}}` .

**Problem:** Currently there is an admin setting for changing email template body. During edit, I want to add a **Hint Notice** to the person making the edit displaying the allowed shortcodes.

E.g **You are editing XYZ template, the allow shortcodes are {{$shortcode1}}, {{$shortcode2}}, and {{$shortcode3}}**

**What I Want to do:** The website has several email template with varying shortcodes, and the templates are prone to be changed or new once added.

To avoid going to each template and listing out each shortcode it has, In the controller, I want to check for the shortcodes in the template, extract them and pass them into the view.

E.g

```
$message = 'Hello {{$first_name}}, you have requested to change your password, your reset link is {{$link}}';

$shortcodes = explode(' ', $message);
```

if I `dd($shortcodes)`, I get this array

```
0 => "Hello"
  1 => "{{$first_name}},"
  2 => "you"
  3 => "have"
  4 => "requested"
  5 => "to"
  6 => "change"
  7 => "your"
  8 => "password,"
  9 => "your"
  10 => "reset"
  11 => "link"
  12 => "is"
  13 => "{{$link}}"
```

Now I want to get all the words starting with `{{$` in the above array, is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use regular expressions here, like this:

```php
$message = 'Hello {{$first_name}}, you have requested to change your password, your reset link is {{$link}}';
        
preg_match_all('/{{\$\w+}}/', $message, $matches);
        
dd($matches[0]);

/*
[
  0 => "{{$first_name}}"
  1 => "{{$link}}"
]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter`:

```
$result = array_filter($words, fn($word) => strpos($word, '{{$') === 0);
```

But perhaps using a regular expression on the email template's text would be a cleaner solution (e.g. with `preg_match_all`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = 'Hello {{$first_name}}, you have requested to change your password, your reset link is {{$link}}';

$shortcodes = explode(' ', $message);

foreach($shortcodes as $sc){
    if( ($sc[0] == "{") && ($sc[1] == "{")  && ($sc[2] == "$") ){
        echo $sc;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why no one uses the function made for this?

```
foreach($shortcodes as $word){
    if(str_starts_with($word, 'x')){
        ## CODE TO BE EXECUTED
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this script:

```
<?php
function getShortCodes($string, $start, $end){
    $count = substr_count($string, $start);
    if ($count == 0) return [];
    $matchings = [];
    for($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++){
        $string = ' ' . $string;
        $ini = strpos($string, $start);
        if ($ini == 0) continue;
        $ini += strlen($start);
        $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
        $subStr = substr($string, $ini, $len);
        $matchings[] = $subStr;
        $string = str_replace('{{$'.$subStr.'}}',"",$string);
        
    }
    return $matchings;
}

$message = 'Hello {{$first_name}}, you have requested to change your password, your reset link is {{$link}}';

$parsed = getShortCodes($message, '{{$', '}}');

print_r($parsed);
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution would be to use `preg_match_all()`

```
$message = 'Hello {{$first_name}}, you have requested to change your password, your reset link is {{$link}}';
preg_match_all('/{{[^{]*}}/', $message, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
//array(1) {
//  [0]=>
//  array(2) {
//    [0]=>
//    string(15) "{{$first_name}}"
//    [1]=>
//    string(9) "{{$link}}"
//  }
//}
```

[here is a jist](https://onlinephp.io/c/d83a2)